# IOS scan for classic bluetooth - get addresses - IBeacons

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I understand the external accessory framework needs to be used to work with Classic Bluetooth on IOS, as a fallback for non BLE phones (i.e Iphone4) , is it possible to scan for devices using the external accessory framework to list Bluetooth addresses that are in range ?

I have Kontakt IBeacons and on android using classic Bluetooth scan i can see all the device addresses, while i cant get UUID's / major and Minor this the Bluetooth device address could still serve to identify some form of proximity to the Beacon...

Is it possible to list devices in range in IOS as well in a similar manner ? i understand the external accessory framework only allows you to pair with complaint devices, but does scanning work for anything in range ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have any access to the visible devices using the External Accessory Framework and classic Bluetooth devices.

The External Accessory Framework handles both cabled and Bluetooth connections and hides the discovery process.  Essentially an application provides the supported device information in the info.plist file. When iOS discovers a matching device then the app is advised - the app doesn't play an active role in scanning for or identifying the device.

As an iBeacon won't have the Apple MFi chip in it, it won't be detected by the External Accessory Framework discovery process.